# Запросы к /xml-table.php, к чему они и зачем?

Tags: php

В логах появилось много запросов к несуществующему файлу `xml-table.php`:

```
GET /xml-table.php HTTP/1.1
```

Понятно, что ищуют какую-то дырявую систему, аналогично как запрашивают `/xmlrpc.php` и `/wp-login.php` для выяснения версии Wordpress (вопрос не про них).

- Для какой конкретно системы предназначены эти запросы?
- Что за дырки пытаются таким образом найти, и, возможно, эксплуатировать?

Поиск по названию этого файла даёт кучу рецептов по созданию XML таблиц из PHP, но ни слова об уязвимостях. Вопрочем, возможно, я как-то не так ищу.

Comment: А что в заголовках? Разные клиенты или всё с одного адреса? Может быть не ищут дыру, а опечатались просто?

Comment: С разных IP. Этот сайт вообще без PHP.

Comment: Cделать чтобы по этому вопросу вернулся 200 и пособирать payload?

Comment: Что должно быть в ответе на такой запрос чтобы пошел POST с payload?

Comment: да откуда я знаю-то. ну XML какой-нибудь. или HTML. это же пальчиком трогают. если не будет 404 - полезут с запросами. Ну я так думаю. Вполне может быть это бот у криворукого скрипт-кидди с ума сошёл, и шлет тупо пустые запросы.

Comment: @sanmai , тю, ну создайте вы пустой файл /xml-table.php, понаблюдайте что будет далее. вам ведь интересно.